# Check if Hashtable.get worked

Tags: java, hashtable

I'm working with on a Java program that checks a `config` file integrity.

On some point, I need to ensure that some **mandatory** values are setted up, either give it a default value.

So, I made a `HashTable<String, String>` working like a `key => value` table. On this table I store all the configuration lines on the file, and then I check it.

The problem comes when a specific value does not exist, for example:

```
String p = null;
/*...*/

//here I'm trying to get the LOG value
p = this.PAIRS.get("LOG");

if(p.equals(null) || p.equals("")){
    //set default value
}
```

The problem is that I'm getting a NullPointerException, so it would be fine if someone can help me on how to determinate if `this.PAIRS.get("LOG");` found a key or not...

Thanks!

---

EDIT: Solved, the right thing was using `==` and not an `equals`.

Thanks again!

Comment: You should look at Properties or HashMap. Properties is designed for configurations and is backed by HashMap.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
p = this.PAIRS.get("LOG");
```

This code return null if the key is not present and when you are doing below statement it will throw exception

```
if(p.equals(null) || p.equals("")){
    //set default value
}
```

Instead check null first then do .equals

```
 if(p==null || p.equals("")){
        //set default value
    }
```

Answer (score 2):

If p is null, a `NullPointerException` will be thrown because it is not an instance of an Object (so the equals method doesn't exist). Checking for null should be done the following way : `p == null`

Comment: Yes, that usually is the case, but there some exceptions (no pun intended) that might be confusing sometimes. The same goes for comparing primitives (The 'things' starting with a lower case character) : int, long, short etc. . Since they are not `Object`s you also can't compare with equals.